# Flutter checkbox customization

Tags: android, flutter, dart, cross-platform

I want to give extra padding to the checkbox `✔️` icon so that it looks like the orange checkbox in the picture. The green one is the default checkbox by flutter(*sorry for the low quality*). Is it possible in flutter?

Default and customized checkbox:
[image: Default and customized checkbox]

```
bool checkBoxValue = true;
Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                      child: Checkbox(
                          visualDensity:
                              const VisualDensity(horizontal: -4, vertical: 0),
                          side: BorderSide(
                            color: Colors.green.withOpacity(0.3),
                            width: 2,
                          ),
                          shape: const CircleBorder(),
                          activeColor: const Color(0xff17B978),
                          value: checkBoxValue,
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            print(value);
                            setState(() {
                              checkBoxValue = value!;
                            });
                          }),
                    ),
```

Comment: Can you include your current checkBox snippet

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I've added my current checkbox snippet.

Answer (score 0):

for custom UI you can use your own image and manage those images using `bool` values checked or unchecked and give them as padding as you want because that is not a `checkbox` widget and you can customize that as you wish.